# phantomsjs works on command but not with exec() PHP

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, phantomjs

I am using Phantomjs and it doesn't work well. I am generating a PDF from my webpage with this command :

```
/var/www/html/hor/js/phantomjs /var/www/html/hor/js/_generate.js 1234
```

It works well (it doesn't find UI-kit js file, I have not yet considered the question) and I have my PDF in my PDF directory. But with my PHP file I have nothing.

Command or PHP both give the following error code with print_r() :

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 
'"default"in t')

http://localhost/js/uikit.min.js:3
http://localhost/js/uikit.min.js:3
http://localhost/js/uikit.min.js:3
```

(So in both cases the script has been launched)

My PHP script :

```
<?php
    $token = $_GET['token'];
    $simul_mail = $_GET['simulmail'];

    $cmd = ' /var/www/html/hor/js/phantomjs';
    $cmd.= ' /var/www/html/hor/js/_generate.js';
    $cmd.= ' '.$token;

    if(isset($_GET['simulmail'])&&isset($_GET['token'])){
        exec($cmd, $output);
    }   
    print_r( $output );
?>
```

My _generate.js file executed by phantomJS :

```
fs = require('fs');
system = require('system');
token = system.args[1];

if(token!=null && token!=""){

    fs.changeWorkingDirectory('/var/www/html/hor/pdf/');

    var page = new WebPage();
    var pagename = "PDF_"+token+".pdf";

    page.open('http://localhost/_template-mail.php?v='+token, function (status) {
        page.render(pagename);
        phantom.exit();
    });

}
else{
    phantom.exit();
}
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ones with the same problem, it was a question about Rights.

Apache did not have the rights to write in my PDF folder.

PhantomJS with exec() uses the rights of PHP which is using rights of Apache.

If Apache is the owner of the folder, it works great !

```
--> sudo chown <your username>:<your usergroup> -R <path to>/folder
sudo chown apache -R /var/www/html/hor/pdf
```